# Mono SOAP request construct for .Net application causes SOAP fault

Tags: .net, soap, jboss, mono, jboss7.x

I have a .Net application which makes a webservice call to a service running on JBoss7.1. The SOAP request for one of the methods 'login' from Linux(using Mono 2.10.2) and Windows(below) are different. Though they look equivalent(I think), executing from Linux causes a server fault with exception **'Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.array.mod.abc.com/", local:"username"). Expected elements are <{}username>,<{}password>'**

```
Linux(Mono 2.10.2)
==================
POST /array_ws/ArrayService?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 335
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: keep-alive
Host: 10.10.5.61:8080

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <login xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://ws.array.mod.abc.com/">
         <username>admin</username>
         <password>admin</password>
      </login>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Windows
=======
POST /array_ws/ArrayService?WSDL HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: 10.10.5.61:8080
Content-Length: 312
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <login xmlns="http://ws.array.mod.abc.com/">
         <username xmlns="">admin</username>
         <password xmlns="">admin</password>
      </login>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When i add xmlns="" to username and password fields and make a direct SOAP call to the server from Linux, it works fine. Is there any mono library i must change / JBoss web service configuration i must do to get it working?

Comment: It looks to me as if the error is on the JBoss side, it's not accepting what looks like valid syntax.

Comment: How can this be resolved? I use the normal annotations & wsgen for the webservice...